# Toggle external elements with bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an external fixed element that should toggle when the bootstrap dropdown is toggled. There are however a few conditions, which are proving tricky.

1. If the user clicks off & hovers off the menu items & logo & fixed element then fixed element & dropdowns disappear
2. If the user toggles between menu items the fixed element remains until the user clicks off
3. If the menu item clicked has no dropdown then the fixed element disappears.

Here is a FSFiddle of what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6PhA/17/

So far I have the hover out hiding the green div, I need to hide the div on .open .dropdown-toggle click which isn't working

```
$(".open .dropdown-toggle").on("click", function(){
    $(".master-sub-menu").animate({"height":"0"},200,function(){
    });
});
```

Anyone any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Looks like your .open class is removed prior... You will need a way to identify better. Perhaps add a .previouslySelected class that only get removed when another dropdown is selected.

Comment: This is very hard to understand, your fiddle shows no green and no logos as far as I can see?  What do you mean by an external fixed element?  Also I think you are trying to compare an array with a single target element which will never give you the comparison you are looking for.  Try looping through each of your `container` items: `header, .master-sub-menu` separately.

Comment: A logo is just an anchor in the header. The fixed element is .master-sub-menu. I'm trying to tie the height of this element into the dropdown click. But when toggling between 2 menu items it shouldn't hide, only if there is a click off or mouse off the header menu items & the master-sub-menu

Comment: I ended up assigning my own classes and toggling outside bootstrap. The classes are removed too quickly to hijack the click event.
Thanks for the help.